# laravel not getting javascript uploaded file with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

When making an alert of variable file, it shows that it contain the file but when going in back it show that there is no file sent, below is my code used

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var sid = getUrlVars()["id"];    

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
    //get file in variable
    var file = fileInput.files[0];

    $("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {

        var inputData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        alert(inputData);
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#message").empty();
        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                   'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ localStorage.token,
                   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
               },
            url: "api/v1/uploadReport/" + sid,
            type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
            data: fileInput,
            async: false,
            contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
            cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
            processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
            success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
            {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $("#message").html(data);
            }
        });
    }));
```

Comment: data: fileInput,
 Shouldnt this be             data: file,

Comment: i changed but nothing changed. the file is not received in backend